# Print com a variável ou pela conta direto?

Tags: c, variáveis, estilo-de-codificação

Estes dois métodos são os mesmos na questão de desempenho? Tem um que é melhor do que o outro ou é melhor no aspecto de organização do código?

> Método 01: direto

```
printf("%.4lf\n", sqrt( pow(x2-x1, 2) + pow(y2-y1, 2) ));
```

> Método 02: por variável

```
    double dist;
    dist = sqrt( pow(x2-x1, 2) + pow(y2-y1, 2) );
    printf("%.4lf\n", dist);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não existe um jeito certo. É uma questão de estilo e até de necessidade.

Eu tendo a não criar variáveis sem necessidade. Mas em cálculos complexos que possua um significado claro em aplicações mais complexos eu posso criar uma variável só para dar um nome para aquilo. E se a variável for criada o nome tem que ser o mais descritivo possível, para fazer sem aumentar muito a legibilidade e tornar o código mais óbvio, não crio.

O que eu não faria, nunca, é declarar a variável em uma linha e atribuir em outra.

Obviamente que se você for usar o valor em dois lugares diferentes, precisar de um passo intermediário ou precisar fazer algo extra antes de usar esse valor aí a variável pode ser obrigatória.

De forma geral não afeta na performance ou consumo de memória, mas algumas situações mais complexas pode sim ser um pouco pior criar a variável. Nada grande e quase sempre sem importância, mas pode ter uma diferença.

Sem ver um contexto eu faria o primeiro, mas sei que algumas pessoas preferem sempre fazer o segundo, com as ressalvas que já fiz antes. Se for para fazer o segundo eu tenderia até criar uma função e assim ter essa fórmula genérica para uso geral.

Comment: O ex era um simples só para aplicar a fórmula.. Mas sempre tive essa dúvida, obrigado pelo esclarecimento.

Comment: Só mais um dúvida, qual seria o motivo de vc não declarar a variável depois da criação dela?

Comment: Qual o motivo para você fazer isso? Não faça coisas que não pode justificar.